# jQuery suppressing 'forward_to' without preventDefault

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that is submitting comments. I want 'forward_to' to move to another page after a jQuery notice is displayed. There is no 'preventDefault' in the jQuery code. When the form is submitted, the data is saved, and the jquery notice is displayed, but 'forward_to' is suppressed. When i remove the id from the form the 'forward_to' works. So what is preventing the forward?

form:

```
<%= form_for @fb_comments, :html => { :'data-type' => 'html', :id => 'comment' } do |form| %>
    ...
    <%= form.submit "Update FEEDBACK" %>
<% end %>
```

jquery notice:

```
//SUBMIT COMMENT CONFIRMATION
$("#comment").submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    alert("Your comments were emailed.");
    return false;
})
```

controller:

```
fbc = FbComments.find(params[:id])
fbc.update_attributes(params[:fb_comments])
redirect_to root_path
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `return false;` is your issue.